# Pandas: Shifting in function: 'ambiguous truth value'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that consist of a dateIndex and a price column, like so:

```
DATE   |     PRICE
01-01-2018    100
02-01-2018    101
03-01-2018    97
```

I've written a function to calculate the difference between the price in a row, and the price 3 rows ('days') before. (I know there are other pandas methods to achieve this, but this function is a stub that I want to expand on later)

```
def case1(x):

  prevrow = x.shift(3)
  if np.isnan(prevrow['price']):
      pass
  else:
      if x['price'] > prevrow['price']:
          diff = prevrow['price'] - x['price']             
          print('The diff is {}').format(diff)
```

However, when I try to run (`case1(df)`) this function I encounter the

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Error. It seems to be triggered on the 3 `NaN` values that are generated by the shift in the beginning of the function. But adding a the check against `NaN` values still results in the same error message.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Nope, it's not triggered by the NaNs. It's the comparison ````x['price'] > prevrow['price']```` that returns a series of True/False values rather than a single value.

Comment: `(x['price'] > prevrow['price']).all()` should work fine instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider a bigger dataframe for better visualization:

```
DATE        |  price
01-01-2018     100
02-01-2018     101
03-01-2018     97
04-01-2018     102
05-01-2018     100
06-01-2018     107
07-01-2018     38
```

You have some problems in your code. You are trying to make a bool operations with arrays instead of a single value. A solution:

```
def case1(x):
    # New df with a new column for shift prices
    df = x.assign(price_prevrow= x.shift(3)['price'])

    if np.isnan(df['price_prevrow']).all(): # Check ALL values
        pass
    else:
        # Slice df to get only rows with price greater than price_prevrow
        df = df.loc[df['price'] > df['price_prevrow']]

        # Calculate difference
        diff = df['price_prevrow'] - df['price']

        # Print all differences
        for d in diff:
            print('The diff is {}'.format(d))
```

The code above create a new dataframe with the shifted prices, than slice this dataframe with rows what have price value greater than the prevrow value. After this get the difference is easy.

Output:

```
"The diff is -2.0"
"The diff is -10.0"
```